# Azure APi Management Split schema definition in multiple ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template

I've defined an API containing multiple operations.
I've split and defined the operations in two separate ARM template, with its related schema definition.
When deploying each template, the schema definitions cannot coexist, and only the latest one are visible in the portal.

Does anyone have a solution to split the operations in multiple templates and supporting update of the API schema? The API does not support multiple schemas, since that would generate an error.

Any ideas?
Thanks
Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can split operations of a single API into multiple ARM templates. Operations under an API is a collection of "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/operations" type resources. So, if you split into multiple, last deployed template will win.

On a separate note, you can refer [Azure API Management DevOps Resource Kit](https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit) in case it helps to make your deployment easier otherwise in general.

Comment: the operations can be split in several template, the issue is actually the schema of those operations; if referencing the same schemaId, the last one deployed will win.
If assigning a different schemaId, that seems to kind of break the definition API, which can't be exported or used in the LogicApp correctly... I was wondering whether there was some alternative that could make the trick